# How to retrieve element from the local storage in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

image url https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFSwR.png

```js
 searchingBtn() {

        if ( this.searchHistory.indexOf(this.search) === -1 && this.search.trim().length>0) {
          this.searchHistory.push(this.search);
        }
        this.search = '';

        const baseURI = 'some url........';   
        
         localStorage.setItem('loggedinUser', response.data.access_token);
    localStorage.getItem('loggedinUser');
    localStorage.setItem('anonymous_id', response.data);
    var searchItem =  localStorage.getItem('anonymous_id');


        const headers = new Headers({
          
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'access_token' : searchItem,
          
        });

        var data={
          'keyword': this.SearchText.value,
         
        }

     
        axios.post(baseURI, data)
        .then((response) => {
          this.users = response;
        }, (error) => {
          if (error) {
            this.errorMessage = error.response.data.message;
          }
        }).catch(error => {
          //this.errorMessage = error.response.data;
        })
    },
```

```html
 <button
        type="submit"
        value="Seaar"
        v-on:click="searchingBtn"
      >
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
      </button>
```

Here is my axios post method, where it will allow to add the recently searched products by a
only registered(login) user to the recent search list.

But the problem with the above code is, I am not even getting any response in the network from the console. Even tried to check the postman collection, there it was success.

Then i come to know the issue, that is because of, Here i need to get the localstorage item from the below(where i am attaching the screen shot for that.)and get the access token and the anonymous user from the localstorage->session->tokeninfo->scope. and in scope i need to get the anonymous id.

and access_token from the localstorage->loggedinuser.
[attaching image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFSwR.png)
Dont know my code is correct for that or not..can you please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

#### Update

This is no longer relevant, as OP changed the question...

---

`localStorage.getItem()` takes only 1 parameter.

`localStorage.setItem()` takes 2 parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i need to getItem from the localStorage. So if i pass only one parameter, How can i do that. From the code the way of calling is it correct.. like response.data from the localstorage....

Comment: Attaching the image for the reference, to make sure i write anything wrong from getting the values. https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFSwR.png